# How to make an annotation file for training this implementation of Tiny-YOLO?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, yolo

So I need to retrain Tiny YOLO using my own dataset. I have the pictures (with and without the bounding boxes on it) and for every picture I have a JSON file. I am using FLIR dataset if that helps people know what I need to do. I will provide an example of JSON file below as well.

I forgot to add that I am using Yolo in Keras. The model I am using can be found here: [keras-yolo3](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3)
.

From what I have how can I make this annotation file for training this implementation of Tiny YOLO?

```
{
    "annotation": [
        {
            "area": 1140,
            "bbox": [
                44,
                235,
                38,
                30
            ],
            "category_id": "3",
            "id": 1,
            "image_id": 12,
            "iscrowd": 0,
            "segmentation": [
                [
                    44,
                    235,
                    44,
                    265,
                    82,
                    265,
                    82,
                    235
                ]
            ]
        }
    ],
    "image": {
        "file_name": "FLIR_00012",
        "height": 512,
        "id": 12,
        "width": 640
    }
}
```

Comment: [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark) might help. To convert the format of JSON files to YOLO, you could use Matlab.

Comment: From what I see this is OpenCV implementation of YOLO.
I forgot to mention that I am using Tensorflow-Keras.
Not sure what you mean convert the format of JSON to YOLO, but I guess you said that cause of OpenCV implementation. Maybe if you look at what I am using you can tell me if that is the case or can I use this (will google it) in my case as well

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3#training), you should convert each of these JSON files to YOLO format, which is `x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max,class_id` for each object. You have all these information alongside with image file name and size in the JSON file. I suggest using [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/326764-how-can-i-read-a-json-file) to read each JSON file and create the **Row format** and **Box format** according to your link. You can search or ask for this conversion. That way you will get better answers.

Comment: Oh I didn't understand you at first. Thank you that helped a lot. I am not sure how to make your answer the one I needed so people know if they run into the same problem